# Help in making convolution and correlation illustration using TikZ package

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I need to make the illustrations for topics of convolution and correlation,
Diagrams need to be made like this image. I am using TikZ package. I am very new to this package and learning it.

Here that, it explains the working inside convolution and correlation kernel.

[image]

List of numbers or variables in two rows are two signals. The line linking two numbers specifies multiplication for convolution or correlation operation. Two signals can be similar or dissimilar like in figure (c). Variable or number in a signal may or may not have overbar on them. Sometime color needs to be different for linkage as in last example.

Comment: This is not a 'do it for me' kind of site. Please provide what you have tried so far and what part of the code you are specifically struggling with. You can start searching this website for examples of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following short example could serve as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(table)[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep =0.5cm,
  nodes={anchor=center,
         minimum width=0.5cm,
         minimum height=0.5cm, 
         },
  ] 
  {
    3 & 8 & 9 & 0 \\
    4 & 5 & 2 &   \\
  };
  \draw [red, very  thick] (table-1-4.south) -- (table-2-1.north);
  \draw [red, very  thick] (table-1-3.south) -- (table-2-2.north);
  \draw [red, very  thick] (table-1-2.south) -- (table-2-3.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```